# How to add *.a files into repository using svnX?

Tags: macos, svn

It seems that svnX silently ignores all *.a files. But I want to add some libraries into repository, how do I do it with svnX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that I had to edit my ~/.subversion/config file.

Uncomment the global-ignores line and remove the *.a file type. After that .a files started showing up.

Comment: but where we found ~/.subversion/config file?

Answer (score 5):

If you only add a `*.a` file occasionally, open `Terminal.app` and execute command:

```
svn add <*.a file path>
```

If successful, the file will appear in `svnX`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about svnX, but in general you might be able to add them manually by naming them explicitly. This overrides the "ignorance".