# how to commit "*.a" file in svnx?

Tags: macos, commit, svnignore, svnx

I already tried this link
([How to add *.a files into repository using svnX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812119/how-to-add-a-files-into-repository-using-svnx))

but didn't find *.a file on my working copy folder in svnx

my svnx version 2.0b2 (https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/svnx/html/index.html)

.a file is third party library. therefore I can not modify file extention as bypass 
I was commit use by eclipse pluggin subversive. but this solution is not convinience.

Comment: "but didn't find *.a file on my working copy folder in svnx".  How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: the .a file is exist in my working copy but can't fine in svnx program. ( maybe svnx ignore .a extension)

Comment: Have you checked `~/.subversion/config`?

Comment: yes I did delete *.a on config

Comment: >>>>*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.pyc *.pyo
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store

Answer (score 0):

On MAC OS - OPEN Terminal to execute below

*cd pathtoProject*

**To ADD**

then You can either force commit the file using  either

*svn add * --force* 
OR
*svn add folderpath/file --force*

OR
change svn config file which would ignore *.a files

*To commit*
svn commit -m "The Commit message"